# edit datatable or add combobox c#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, combobox

this code in c# windows forms populate my combobox with data of mysql database, and he work

```
 conn.Open();
 string query = "SELECT * FROM FRUITS";
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
 MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);
 comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "NAME";
 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "NAME";
```

But, i need one of two options:

1. Add a row in FIRST POSITION of combobox.
2. Add a row in FIRST POSITION of dataTable.

example: this code return to me a combobox with values  "Banana" and "Apple" but i need the first value is "Select one Fruit".

if i using the next code after "da.Fill(dt)", he add a row in dataTable and appear in combobox, BUT after the "Apple", combobox=("Banana", "Apple", "Select one Fruit") but i need ("Select one fruit", "Banana", "Apple")

```
 dt.Rows.Add("Select One Fruit");
```

How i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it.

ComboBox

`combobox1.Items.Insert(0, "Select a fruit");`

DataTable

`dt.Rows.InsertAt(row,0);`

Comment: work but i can add only int32, don´t can with string "Select a fruit"

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
dt.Rows.InsertAt
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat.aspx

OR

```
combobox1.Items.Insert
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.insert.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert item into a comboBox, when DataSource property is in use. you got an exception: "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.".
But if you add a new row at 0 index to  dataTable before you set it as a datasource it works well

```
 conn.Open();
 string query = "SELECT * FROM FRUITS";
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
 MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);

//Add new row
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["NAME"] = "Select a fruit";
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);

comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "NAME";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "NAME";
```